# Is it possible to increase the speed at which Microsoft Graph Notifications for Call Records are generated?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am receiving Microsoft Graph notifications via a subscription to the /communications/callrecords resource.  On average, these notifications are taking about 5 minutes to arrive after a call has occurred.  Sometimes they take 12 to 15 minutes to arrive.  Is there a way to increase the speed at which these notifications are delivered?  Alternatively, is there another way to retrieve this data?

(I understand that the call records resource does not yet have Delta query functionality that other Graph resources do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latency for change notifications to be received depend on a lot of factors. It depends on the service load: depending on how many calls are happening and how busy is the service that generates the recording, it can take more or less time to generate the recording. The length of the meeting can impact generation time. Once the recording is generated the service load can also impact change notification emission and delivery.

Finally, if your notification URL has been tagged as slow, change notifications will be delayed as well.

There is nothing you can do to impact this latency and as far as I know, no other notification system is available for that data today.